# PLCrashReporter header implementation?

Tags: ios, plcrashreporter

I need to implement the PLCrashReporter to my application, i have added framework and the code to use it, but i need add header files. I am not sure what to add as header files.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "CrashReporter/CrashReporter.h"
```

Would be the right answer, if all is right configured.

Comment: It should be `#import <CrashReporter/CrashReporter.h>`